# procedural logic calculating averages using visual basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to calculate an average using Visual Basic 2010 and display this average in a message window. Whilst debugging (commenting out code and trying different variables being sent to the message box as string) I got the message window to appear, but with no data returned.

As I have the code now, I do not receive any errors, but I can't even get the message box to appear.

Basically the program has the user enter a number of books they have read which is then used to calculate a point total based on the amount of books read. The exercise asks to keep a average of all the books read.

```
Public Class BookPoints

'Declare module level variables for summary information
Private PointInteger, BookAmountInteger, SummaryBookTotal, ReaderCount As Integer

Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click
    'Exit the program
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub ClearToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ClearToolStripMenuItem.Click
    With NameTextBox2
        .Clear()
        .Focus()
        .Select()
    End With
    BooksTextBox1.Clear()
    PointsTextBox3.Clear()
End Sub

Private Function Points(ByVal BookAmountInteger As Integer) As Integer
    'Calculate point total
    If BookAmountInteger <= 3 Then
        Return BookAmountInteger * 10
    ElseIf BookAmountInteger >= 4 AndAlso BookAmountInteger <= 6 Then
        Return 30 + (BookAmountInteger - 3) * 15
    Else
        Return 75 + (BookAmountInteger - 6) * 20
    End If
End Function

Private Sub PointsToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PointsToolStripMenuItem.Click
    'calculate points and display total
    Try
        PointInteger = Integer.Parse(BooksTextBox1.Text)
        PointsTextBox3.Text = Points(PointInteger).ToString()
    Catch BookAmountException As FormatException
        MessageBox.Show("Amount of books read must numeric.", _
                        "Data Entry Error", _
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        With BooksTextBox1
            .Clear()
            .Focus()
            .Select()
        End With

        'calculate average of books read
        Dim Total As Decimal
        Total = Decimal.Parse(BooksTextBox1.Text)

        If Total <> 0 Then
            Total += SummaryBookTotal
            ReaderCount += 1
        End If
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub SummaryToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SummaryToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim AverageBooks As Decimal
    Dim MessageString As String

    If ReaderCount > 0 Then
        AverageBooks = SummaryBookTotal / ReaderCount

        MessageString = "Average books read: " &
            SummaryBookTotal.ToString()
        MessageBox.Show(MessageString, "Average of Books Read", _
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: For a first quick look `SummaryBookTotal` is always 0.

Comment: So that total =decimal.parse is not returning a value form the text box?

Comment: I mean, you have a variable `SummaryBookTotal` and never either assign a value or update. So it remains 0.  `Total += SummaryBookTotal` is always `Total += 0` and `AverageBooks = 0`

Comment: so how can I take the value from BookTextBox1 and use it to maintain a running count of the books entered and then return that value as an average?

Comment: Maybe you need to change `Total += SummaryBookTotal` to `SummaryBookTotal += Total`

Comment: yeah no dice. I know my logic is flawed, just can't figure out how or where...

Comment: You dont explain the logic of calculating the evarage. The Points function does what?

Comment: I am going to suggest possibly starting over. Delete the calculating function and simply try to take the average (whatever kind of "Average" calculation you're using....) of the BooksTextBox1. So,
`Dim numBooks As Integer = Integer.Parse(BooksTextBox1.Text)
Dim bookAvg As Integer

If numBooks <= 3 Then
      bookAvg = numBooks * 10 etc...
PointsTextBox3.Text = bookAvg.ToString()`

Comment: I find it weird that the code under "'calculate average of books read" is inside your catch block. This mean it will only be executed if there's an error.